# Add a value to a Ajax post in mvc3

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I need to add a value from a hidden field into my Ajax post.

I'm afraid i do not know a lot about Ajax so I will try to explain what i need:

In my view page I have the following:

```
 <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<div class="OneBySevenBin2">
    <div class="OneBySevenBin2middle">
        <div class="divTitleArea">
            <p>
            </p>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <% if (Model.ProductNotFound)
               { %>
            <!-- List the retailers as we have none in stock -->
            <%= Html.WidgetProductNotFoundList(Model) %>
            <% }
               else
               { %>
            <% using (Html.BeginForm())
               {%>
            <%= Html.AntiForgeryToken() %>
            <%= Html.WidgetProductFoundListThreeStageBin2(Model)%>
            <div class="stepFour" data-bind="stopBinding: true">
                <% if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Confirmation))
                   {
                       Ajax.BeginForm("OneBySevenBin2",  new AjaxOptions()
                                                      {

                                                          HttpMethod = "POST"
                                                      });
                       { %>
                <div id="uandp">
                    <p>
                        <input type="text" name="username" class="txtUsername" id="email" value="Username" />
                        <%= Html.ValidationMessage("Email", "Please enter a valid Email") %>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <input type="password" name="password" class="txtPassword" value="Password" />
                    </p>
                    <input type="hidden" id="hiddenVal" class="hiddenVal" name="hiddenVal" value="1" />
                </div>
                <div id="rightaddtocart">
                    <div id="divaddtocartbtn">
                        <input type="image" class="buynow" id="imgaddtocart" alt="Add to Cart" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/images/addtobasketbutton.png" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <% } %>
                <% }
                   else
                   { %>
                <p>
                    <%-- <%= ViewBag.Confirmation %>--%>
                    <img class="divAdded" src="http://static.e-talemedia.net/content/images/Basketmessage.png"
                        alt="Added to Basket" />
                </p>
                <% } %>
            </div>
            <% } %>
            <%-- This is the quantity--%>
            <div class="qty">
                <button id="delete" class="minusQty">
                </button>
                <div id="theCount" class="theCount">
                </div>
                <button id="addMe" class="addQty">
                </button>
            </div>
            <% } %>
        </ul>        
    </div>
</div>
<%= Html.WidgetImpressionCode(Model) %>
<%= Html.WidgetTrackingCode(Model) %>
```

The following:

```
     <%= Html.WidgetImpressionCode(Model) %>
```

Goes to a widget helper which omits a script as follows:

```
 <input id="e-taleWidgetImpressionId" name="e-taleWidgetImpressionId" type="hidden" value="" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function () {
    var manufacturerWidgetId = "260";
    var productId = "6572";
    var countryId = "230";
    var theUrl = "http://localhost:1579/Widgets/Impression/260/6572/230/9r22r45r80";
    $.getJSON(theUrl + "?callback=?", {}, callback);

    function callback(data) {
            var widgetImpressionId = data.Id;
            $("input[name='e-taleWidgetImpressionId']").val(widgetImpressionId);

            }
        });
        //]]>
    </script>
```

I need to include the value of the hidden field in the ajax post

```
<input id="e-taleWidgetImpressionId" name="e-taleWidgetImpressionId" type="hidden" value="" />
```

This is so I can use it in the controller:

```
  [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult OneBySevenBin2(String modelNo, string widgetImpressionId, string page, FormCollection form)
        {
...
}
```

Comment: Thats MVC2 isn't it? MVC3 would use the Razor `@` syntax

Comment: @Liam that is not necessary in mvc3 the `<%` syntax can be used

Comment: @anna, dakit is right but Razor makes for much cleaner code. If you want to use this, thats fine, but maybe read this: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/07/02/introducing-razor.aspx

Comment: @anna are you setting the value of hidden field by javascript?

Answer (score 1):

where is your ajax `post` code in the question? `getJSON` uses the `GET` request any way you can add the hidden field data like

```
$.ajax({
 url:'',
 type:'',
 data:{hdnField:$("#e-taleWidgetImpressionId").val()},
 ...
});
```

on the server side it could be recieved as

```
         [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
        public ActionResult OneBySevenBin2(String modelNo, string widgetImpressionId, string page, FormCollection form,string hdnField)
        {
         ...
         }
```